# Nested Parallel.For loop performance and Large Lists

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, locking, parallel.for

The code I'm executing has a simple function. It compares the first 2 Items of a Tuple (`Tuple<int, int, BigInteger>`) with another, and determines if all entries are distinct. If they are, a combined Tuple (`Tuple<int, int, int, int BigInteger>`) is formed and added to a `List<Tuple<int, int, int, int, BigInteger>>`

Example:

```
    Tuple<int, int, BigInteger> example1 = new Tuple<int, int BigInteger>(5, 6, 1000);
    Tuple<int, int, BigInteger> example2 = new Tuple<int, int BigInteger>(7, 9, 7979);
```

Since 5, 6, 7 and 9 are all different, they are added to the final List as <5, 6, 7, 9, 1000+7979> (Item5 being a sum of Item3 in Tuple1 and Tuple2)

Here's my code

```
    for (int a = 0; a < rtSort.Count(); a++) {
            Parallel.For<List<Tuple<int, int, int, int, BigInteger>>>(0, rtSort.Count - 1, () => new List<Tuple<int, int, int, int, BigInteger>>(), (b, loop, storage) => {
                if (rtSort[a].Item1 != rtSort[b].Item1 && rtSort[a].Item1 != rtSort[b].Item2 && rtSort[a].Item2 != rtSort[b].Item2)
                    storage.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int, int, BigInteger>(rtSort[a].Item1, rtSort[a].Item2, rtSort[b].Item1, rtSort[b].Item2, rtSort[a].Item3 + rtSort[b].Item3));
                return storage;
            },
            (x) => {
                lock (rt2) {
                    rt2.AddRange(x);
                }
            });
    }
```

I already know that Items within the same Tuple will not be the same so I just have to check against the other one

the `rtSort.Count()` usually has a value of 500500, meaning that in total, the nested `Parallel.For` loop and the `For` loop does 500500*500500 iterations before finishing (250500250000).

My question is: Is there anything I can do to improve this and/or am I doing something wrong that could actually be impeding the Parallel.For loop's performance

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of rt2 ?

Comment: List<Tuple<int, int, int, int, BigInteger>>

Comment: What happens if there are 3 tuples with the first two values the same?

Comment: There are never 3 tuples being checked at a time. Only 2 at a time

Comment: Just curious about the context for this problem. In the worst case scenario for the case presented, 250 billion tuples could be created.  This seems a bit extreme when dealing with 500K items.

Comment: I'm computing solutions for an equation and then comparing this programs output with another set of data from a different output for overlap and final results

Answer (score 1):

The lock can be an issue if the AddRange takes to long , if order is not important in the result

I would benchmark your current implementation , and using ConcurrentBag

```
   var result =  new ConcurrentBag<Tuple<int, int, int, int, BigInteger>>();

    ...

    (x) => {
        foreach(var item in x)
        {
            result.Add(x);
        }        
    })
```

Comment: How do I implement the ConcurrentBag into the entire loop?

Comment: ConcurrentBag  is a data structure, that locks per add of single element ,unlike your implementation which lock until all elements are added